# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1062 Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, crud

Every time I add data it will always start on id number 5 so when I add another data it will error... Can someone help me?

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '5' for key 'PRIMARY'
>
> INSERT INTO `gallery` (`id_gallery`, `name`, `image`) VALUES
>   ('5bbd81467f388', 'steak', 'IMG_1232.JPG')
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/eat/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Controller:Gallery.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gallery extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("gallery_model");
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data["gallery"] = $this->gallery_model->getAll();
        $this->load->view("admin/gallery/list", $data);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $gallery = $this->gallery_model;
        $validation = $this->form_validation;
        $validation->set_rules($gallery->rules());

        if ($validation->run()) {
            $gallery->save();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Berhasil disimpan');
        }

        $this->load->view("admin/gallery/new_form");
    }

    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        if (!isset($id)) redirect('admin/gallery');

        $gallery = $this->gallery_model;
        $validation = $this->form_validation;
        $validation->set_rules($gallery->rules());

        if ($validation->run()) {
            $gallery->update();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Berhasil disimpan');
        }

        $data["gallery"] = $gallery->getById($id);
        if (!$data["gallery"]) show_404();

        $this->load->view("admin/gallery/edit_form", $data);
    }

    public function delete($id=null)
    {
        if (!isset($id)) show_404();

        if ($this->gallery_model->delete($id)) {
            redirect(site_url('admin/gallery'));
        }
    }
}
```

Model: Gallery_model.php

```
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model
{
    private $_table = "gallery";
    public $id_gallery;
    public $name;
    public $image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required']
        ];
    }

    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->db->get($this->_table)->result();
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ["id_gallery" => $id])->row();
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
//        $this->id_gallery = uniqid();
        $this->name = $post["name"];
        $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $this);
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->id_gallery = $post["id"];
        $this->name = $post["name"];
        if (!empty($_FILES["image"]["name"])) {
            $this->image = $this->_uploadImage();
        } else {
            $this->image = $post["old_image"];
        }
        $this->db->update($this->_table, $this, array('id_gallery' => $post['id']));
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->_deleteImage($id);
        return $this->db->delete($this->_table, array("id_gallery" => $id));
    }

    private function _uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './upload/galery/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['upload_max_filesize']  = '100000M';
        $config['post_max_size']        = '100000M';
        $config['file_name']            = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $config['overwrite']            = true;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
            return $this->upload->data("file_name");
        }
    }

    private function _deleteImage($id)
    {
        $gallery = $this->getById($id);
        if ($gallery->image != "default.jpg") {
            $filename = explode(".", $gallery->image)[0];
            return array_map('unlink', glob(FCPATH."upload/galery/$filename.*"));
        }
    }

}
```

Views:new_form.php

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('success'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <a href="<?php echo site_url('admin/gallery/') ?>"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Back</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="<?php base_url('admin/gallery/add')?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Title*</label>
                                    <input class="form-control <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'is-invalid':'' ?>"
                                     type="text" name="name" placeholder="gallery name">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <?php echo form_error('name') ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="image">Photo</label>
                                    <input class="form-control-file <?php echo form_error('name') ? 'is-invalid':'' ?>"
                                     type="file" name="image">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        <?php echo form_error('image') ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="btn" value="Save" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer small text-muted">
                            * required fields
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Make sure the value for this ID is unique and not duplicate : id_gallery

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me example? @Salah

Comment: $this->id_gallery = uniqid();

Why is this line commented in Gallery_model.php?

Comment: Ohh.. I get it now, I see it on tutorial

Comment: Primary keys in db are unique. Check how that id is created by your model and passed to the save method.  If you don’t want unique keys then change your db

Comment: Is `id_gallery` set as a Primary Key field in your database? PK fields cannot contain duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Integer try change your type field for *id_gallery* from int->PRIMARY into varchar->PRIMARY, and dont use Auto Increment on your Database.
It works for me :3